# Why embedded linux(yocto) can't use whole memory of rootfs partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, memory, embedded

I've build Linux image with yocto and deployed it on IMX6qpsabreauto board.

Filesystem was deployed on a second partition of SD Card formatted to ext4.

Everything seems to work fine except that I have 15GB partition for rootfs and system actually using only around 1GB and already run out of space.

I can't see why so. Imx6 seems to see all the memory on the partition.

```
root@imx6qpsabreauto:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk2: 15.9 GB, 15931539456 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 486192 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/mmcblk2p1              33       15296      488448   c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/mmcblk2p2           15297      486192    15068672  83 Linux
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary

root@imx6qpsabreauto:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               976.6M    906.5M    384.0K 100% /
devtmpfs                847.3M         0    847.3M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1007.7M    172.0K   1007.5M   0% /run
tmpfs                  1007.7M    240.0K   1007.4M   0% /var/volatile

root@imx6qpsabreauto:~# cat /etc/mtab 
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=867636k,nr_inodes=216909,mode=755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /var/volatile tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

UPD:
The problem was that I have copied the whole image, but it was better to copy just files from image

```
 mkdir ~/mnt
 mkdir ~/mnt/target
 mkdir ~/mnt/yocto
 sudo mount /dev/sdf2 ~/mnt/target/
 sudo mount -o loop tmp/deploy/images/imx6qpsabreauto/fsl-image-machine-test-imx6qpsabreauto.ext4 ~/mnt/yocto/
 sudo cp -a ~/mnt/yocto/* ~/mnt/target
 sudo umount ~/mnt/target
 sudo umount ~/mnt/yocto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you deploy the rootfs on the SD card? Was it an EXT4 image that you copied on `/dev/mmcblkp2`?

The SD card partition is 15 GB in size, but maybe the actual EXT4 filesystem image that you copied on it is only 1 GB?

Comment: I have build file system image with yocto and copied it with dd utility like this
sudo dd if=fsl-image-gui-imx6qsabresd.ext4 of=/dev/sdd2 bs=1M
When dd was done he wrote that he copied 1.1 Gb, so is the problem that I need to expand file system after deploy so it will fill the whole partition?

Comment: That's right. Your filesystem is only 1 GB in size. Does Yocto also create a gzipped tar archive of the filesystem? You could create an empty EXT4 filesystem on /dev/mmcblkp2 using mkfs.ext4 that will cover the entire partition, mount it and then untar the Yocto filesystem there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, just copying files solved the problem.